# Unit testing a support class within a c# Visual 2010 website

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I would like to start unit testing support classes that are within a website project. In a perfect world the website's support classes would have been placed inside a seperate assembly thus making unit testing very straight forward. What would be the best pattern to automate unit testing of support classes.

Comment: does referencing the website project from the test project not work for you? The default Mvc project template does this but there is no reason you can't set it up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your unit tests don't have to link to an assembly.  They can link and build the CS files directly.

Right click your project, select the Add -> Existing Item option.  Browse to the code, and select what you want to add.  Instead of clicking the "Add" button, which would *copy* the files, click the little arrow on the side of the "Add" button, and select "Add As Link" from the drop-down menu.

Using this approach, you can link directly to the code in your test project, without needing a compiled assembly.  Also, whenever the code changes, your unit test project will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have loads of money and time then testing with the shot gun approach makes sense. Infact test until you are blue in the face. The thing to consider is the 80/20 rule its only about 20% of your tests that are going to give you 80% of your value.

Try to focus on the critical path and then based on that all code that is referenced will be automatically tested.